# Python:Putting two options in an if statement

Tags: python

I have been trying to put two options in an if statement but it never comes up with the correct variable.

```
if size == "8" or 10:
  size_cost = 0
else:
  size_cost = 2
print(size_cost)
```

When the user puts in a number that is bigger that 10 it should print out 2 but what it actaally prints out is 0. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if size == "8" or size == "10":
  size_cost = 0
else:
  size_cost = 2
print(size_cost)
```

Are you sure though that your variable `size` is a string and not an int? You may want to double check this. In this case, you want:

```
if size == 8 or size == 10:
  size_cost = 0
else:
  size_cost = 2
print(size_cost)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It was for a school project so the prompt reply is so useful

Answer (score 0):

need to include the size after the or

```
 if size == 8 or size == 10:
      size_cost = 0
    else:
      size_cost = 2
    print(size_cost)
```